# Replace variable length string with characters to matching original string length

Tags: regex, awk

I am using a regular expression:

```
>\.*<
```

to match certain parts of field3 but I can't figure out how to replace with a number of characters that would preserve the original string length.

Input:

```
field1 field2 >>>>>.>............>>>.........<<<.......>>>>.......<<<<.<.<<<<<.
```

Expected output:

```
field1 field2 >>>>>.>............>>LLLLLLLLLLL<<.......>>>LLLLLLLLL<<<.<.<<<<<.
```

My poor failing attempt:

```
awk 'match($3, />\.*</){split($3, sst, "");for(i=RSTART;i<=RLENGTH;i++){sst[i]="L"};joined=sep="";for(x=1; x in sst;x++){joined=joined sep sst[x];sep=""};printf("%s\n", joined)}' hg19-matRNA.tsv > test2.tsv
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With Perl, it is much clearer, something like `perl -pe 's/>(\.*)</">" . "L" x length($1) . "<"/eg'`

Comment: You'd make it much easier on yourself (and on us trying to help you) if you didn't cram all of your code onto one line. White space is surprisingly cheap these days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($3,/(.*)(>\.*<)(.*)/,a) ) {
        $3 = a[1] gensub(/./,"L","g",a[2]) a[3]
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
field1 field2 >>>>>.>............>>LLLLLLLLLLL<<.......>>>LLLLLLLLL<<<.<.<<<<<.
```

With any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($3,/>\.*</) ) {
        tgt = substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(/./,"L",tgt)
        $3 = substr($3,1,RSTART-1) tgt substr($3,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
field1 field2 >>>>>.>............>>LLLLLLLLLLL<<.......>>>LLLLLLLLL<<<.<.<<<<<.
```

Answer (score 0):

**awk** solution. You could use patsplit as well like this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
  patsplit($3, a, ">\\.+<", seps)
  l=(length(a)>length(seps)?length(a):length(seps))
  for (i=0; i<l; i++){
     if (i in a) gsub(/./,"L",a[i])
     s=s sprintf("%s", (i in a)?a[i]seps[i]:seps[i])
  }
  $3=s
}1

$ awk -f tst.awk file
field1 field2 >>>>>.>............>>LLLLLLLLLLL<<.......>>>LLLLLLLLL<<<.<.<<<<<.
```